# Root device has 2.9GB disk space free, but throws disk full errors

Tags: disk-usage, disk

Here's some console output below to illustrate the problem. **I was able to work around this by clearing out old packages** which gave me 4.6GB free, but I wanted to pose this question here out of curiosity as I've been working with Unix/Linux environments for over a decade now and haven't ever seen anything like this, nor where to start troubleshooting it. Doesn't make any sense.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-34:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            487M     0  487M   0% /dev
tmpfs           100M  3.0M   97M   4% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  4.6G  2.9G  62% /
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-34:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-65 linux-headers-4.4.0-65-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-66 linux-headers-4.4.0-66-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-70 linux-headers-4.4.0-70-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-71 linux-headers-4.4.0-71-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-72 linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-75 linux-headers-4.4.0-75-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-78 linux-headers-4.4.0-78-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-79 linux-headers-4.4.0-79-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-81 linux-headers-4.4.0-81-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-83 linux-headers-4.4.0-83-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-87 linux-headers-4.4.0-87-generic linux-image-4.4.0-65-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-92
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-92
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 149 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/9,876 kB of archives.
After this operation, 70.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 429900 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.4.0-92_4.4.0-92.115_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.4.0-92 (4.4.0-92.115) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-4.4.0-92_4.4.0-92.115_all.deb (--unpack):
 error creating directory './usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-92/tools/lib/bpf': No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-4.4.0-92_4.4.0-92.115_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Also check `df -i` output.

Comment: Didn't think to check inodes, but i doubt that's it. Even though I worked around this, there isn't enough in use close to causing this problem.

Comment: Add what filesystem/mount options you are using (output of mount) as modern file systems can do funky stuff and not report accurate usage in df.

Comment: @MichaelDaffin ext4, fstab options are `default,discard`, mount outputs `rw,relatime,discard,data=ordered`

Comment: the underlying filesystem where this VM is could be full.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro the possibility did cross my mind, but it's an EC2 instance. AWS's infrastructure is fairly reliable and I've never encountered this issue before on their platform.

Comment: do you have a $TMPDIR var or similar defined? Have you done `lsof -n | grep deleted`?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro nope, the closest env var defined is XDG_DATA_DIRS. The lsof command doesn't return anything when I grep the output for "deleted"

Comment: have you tried to reboot the system?

Comment: @isaac that was the first thing I did, the console output is from after I rebooted

Comment: do you run regularly  apt-get clean ? what is the system doing btw? could be logs....have you tried `cd /var ; du -sh`?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro no, not unless it's automated. It's running a lemp stack hosting a small wordpress blog. Last login was in early April. I usually let it run unless I get outage alerts

Comment: The system is not big. I would be wary of /var/cache/apt/archives and of Apache logs growing. Maybe changing the weekly rotation for daily; or consider adding another disk/partition for /var/log

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro if that were the problem, why does `df` show several GB free on the root partition?

Comment: Seems it's time for `fsck`

Comment: Did you actually check the inode usage, or did you just dismiss the idea as unlikely? Also if you've resolved the issue, any information you gather now will be inaccurate, so there's not much we can do to help you.

Comment: Try `tune2fs -m1 /dev/xvda1`, since it's an ext4 fs you might have hit the reserved blocks limit. Also if /boot is on another partition, it might be full, ubuntu loves to fill up /boot!

Comment: @Patrick I was looking for a logical explanation for why this happened in the first place, not help fixing it. I checked the inode usage after the fact. It was 33% in use then. That's why I dismissed it as unlikely.

Comment: Can you append a few dozen kilobytes of stuff (more than one disk block) to an existing file? This will help determine if you're out of disk blocks or out of  inodes.